# How to browse a File and Send it via Bluetooth to the connected device?

Tags: android, file, sockets, bluetooth, chat

**Obs: I know that here have many questions about this, but none of them do what i want, seriously, so don't downvote it due to `Duplicate` question, thanks.**

Well, i have a application that have all the necessary `Bluetooth` classes for connection and managing and etc. My application is a `Chat` via `Bluetooth`, i can send string messages to another device and the other device can send to me too. `Server` and `Client`.

Here is my method to send `Message` (working)

```
public boolean sendMessageByBluetooth(String msg){
    try {
        if(dataOutputStream != null){
            dataOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            return true;
        }else{
            sendHandler(ChatActivity.MSG_TOAST, context.getString(R.string.no_connection));
            return false;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LogUtil.e(e.getMessage());

        sendHandler(ChatActivity.MSG_TOAST, context.getString(R.string.failed_to_send_message));
        return false;
    }
}
```

I want, if possible, a method that is similar to that method, that can `Send Files` so i can use the same source to implement the `File Transfer`.

But i need to have a functionality on my app that is a `File Transfer`, that have a `Browse` button to search a file on your `Device` and then select it and send to paired device, simple as that.

Too, i want to see a `ProgressBar` filling to the user see how long it will take to send the file :)

How i can do that?

**--EDIT--**

I am trying the `File Transfer` here is what i did:

`FileActivity.java`

onCreate event to connect:

```
verifyAndActivateBluetooth(); //this function is same used on ChatActivity it is working.
registerFilter(); //this function is same used on ChatActivity it is working.
chatBusinessLogic.startFoundDevices(); //this function is same used on ChatActivity and it is working.
```

Then i choose the visible another device and it connect successful.

After connected Then..

Button `Browse` -> Intent to show the file explorer:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_FOUND);
```

FileActivity onActivityResult `switch(requestCode)`:

```
case FILE_FOUND:
    filename = data.getData().getPath(); //here was the problem of error 1. now fixed
    if(filename.trim().length() > 0){

        if(chatBusinessLogic.sendFile(filename)){
            lblFilename.setText(filename);
            toastUtil.showToast("Success");
        }
    }else{
        toastUtil.showToast("fail");
    }
```

The `chatBusinessLogic.sendFile(filename)` :

```
public boolean sendFile(String file){

    if(bluetoothComunication != null){
        return bluetoothComunication.sendFileByBluetooth(file);
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

the `bluetoothComunication.sendFileByBluetooth(file)`:

public boolean sendFileByBluetooth(String fpath){

```
File f = new File(fpath);
int n  = 0;
byte b[] = new byte[(int) f.length()];
try
{
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(fpath)); //ERROR FIXED
    DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(dataOutputStream);
    while (-1 != (n = fileInputStream.read(b))){
        dataOutputStream.write(b, 0, n);
    }
    dataOut.flush();
    fileInputStream.close();
    dataOut.close();
    return true;
}catch(IOException e)
{
    LogUtil.e("Error converting file");
    LogUtil.e(e.getMessage());
    return false;
}
```

i was getting this error(**NOW IT IS FIXED**):
If i choose android native method for physical path:

```
/content:/com.estrongs.files/mnt/sdcard/calc-history.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

If i choose alternative method for physical path:

```
/file:/mnt/sdcard/calc-history.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

The error above was fixed using `filename = data.getData().getPath();` on the case `FILE_FOUND` instead of `filename = data.getDataString();`

Now i have another error on this line:

```
dataOutputStream.write(b, 0, n);
```

The error message is that: `Transport endpoint is not connected`, what i should do?

Answer (score 2):

To browse your device use something like [aFileChooser](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser) (there are a lot more than that. google it;). 
You can use the `dataOutputStream/dataInputStream` to send/receive the file as well like you already did with the message. 
Did you try the [ACTION_SEND](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND)-Intent yet? It could work that way too.

The [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) is an android widget which is ready to use, that should not be a problem.

If you need general info use the [Android Developers Guide](http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html) (you probably do already). Almost everything concerning android can be found there, you just have to look.


**EDIT :** (from comment)

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(<filepath>);
DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(out);
int n = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
while (-1 != (n = fin.read(buffer))) {
       dOut.write(buffer, 0, n);
}
dOut.flush();
fin.colse();
dOut.close();
```

hope this is understandable.

Comment: but i don't know what to do with `dataOutputStream/dataInputStream` using a `File`, what i should do after getting the file physical path?

Comment: the outputStream fom your connection

Comment: i still dont understand the `out` var, what `outputStream` ?

Comment: the ouputstream you get calling `getOutputStream()` on your bluetooth socket

Comment: im getting a error: `/file:/mnt/sdcard/calc-history.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)` but the directory is right - see my edit

Comment: Your path should be `/mnt/sdcard/calc-history.txt` without the `/file:` up front. `/file:/mnt/sdcard/calc-history.txt` is the uri not the path.

Comment: Thanks, i've corrected that in the `FileActivity onActivityResult`in the case `FILE_FOUND` i was getting `data.getDataString();` i've changed it to `data.getData().getPath();` but now im getting another error see edit

Answer (score 0):

To pick a file from gallery, I do this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

And to get the file path when you select it from gallery and share it on different apps(like bluetooth, gmail, whatsapp etc), I do this in onActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                   Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                            sendIntent.setType("file/*");
                            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                                    selectedImage);
                            // startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent));
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,
                                    "Share file via:"));
                 }
catch(Exception e)
{
}
}
```

Comment: i cant have more options than `Bluetooth` to `Share` file, is possible to automatically choose `Bluetooth`? :)

Comment: @ Paulo Roberto: Late for bounty XD
Anyways, add this to intent:
intent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth"); 

Replace startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,
                                    "Share file via:"));

with

startActivity(sendIntent);